# Keras History is empty

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I'm working on an LSTM network to predict Electrical load situations... When trying to tune my parameters I would like to use the History callback to get val_loss. 
But when I use the validation_split when fitting the model, the history return is empty. 
If I however take the validation_split away, history contains the 'loss' values. 
Since I am very new to this I have no idea what's going on!
Would be very thankful if someone could give me some hints on what's going on.

```
train_x, train_y = to_supervised(train, n_input)
n_timesteps, n_features, n_outputs = train_x.shape[1], train_x.shape[2], train_y.shape[1]
train_y = train_y.reshape((train_y.shape[0], train_y.shape[1], 1))
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(nd1, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_timesteps, n_features)))
model.add(RepeatVector(n_outputs))
model.add(LSTM(nd2, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(nd5, activation='relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer = optimizer)
model.summary()
history = model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=ep, verbose=verbose, validation_split = 0.2)
print(history.history)
```

I'm not sure what you guys would need to know, but above is the function to build my model.
Please just tell me what you need know.

Thank You!

Comment: What is the output of `print(history.history.keys())` .?

Comment: This returns this: dict_keys([])
I might also add that I have to have verbose = 0 to not get a AttributeError.
I've been reading about this and it seems to be related to the batch size in some way.